# A site for pimp my Notepad

Tags: styles, notepad, ascii-art

Is there any site which have premade words and stuff for Notepad like:

```
 ______   ___    ___
/\  _  \ /\_ \  /\_ \
\ \ \L\ \\//\ \ \//\ \      __     __   _ __   ___ 
 \ \  __ \ \ \ \  \ \ \   /'__`\ /'_ `\/\`'__\/ __`\
  \ \ \/\ \ \_\ \_ \_\ \_/\  __//\ \L\ \ \ \//\ \L\ \
   \ \_\ \_\/\____\/\____\ \____\ \____ \ \_\\ \____/
    \/_/\/_/\/____/\/____/\/____/\/___L\ \/_/ \/___/
                                   /\____/
                                   \_/__/
```

Comment: lol, "pimp my notepad". +1 for entertainment value

Comment: Heh ... we used to do this kinda sigs by hand. IMO, always looks nicer white on black.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an [ASCII Art Generator](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/) which may help you out.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the myriad of generators floating around on the web, there are also programs to do this. The most well known is probably [figlet](http://www.figlet.org/).

Answer (score 2):

[ASCII Cats](http://www.xmission.com/~emailbox/ascii_cats.htm) is quite good, if you like cats.

Comment: I don't know... many of the examples are kinda deformed and disturbing - *especially* if you like cats.

Comment: One of them also appears to be written in Lisp (hint: search for 11 consecutive closing brackets).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ascii-art.de/ascii/

Answer (score 1):

Online ASCII text-art generators:

- [Text ASCII Art Generator](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/)
- [ASCII Generator](http://www.network-science.de/ascii/)

Offline ASCII text-art generators:

- [FIGlet](http://www.figlet.org/)

Online ASCII Art Collections:

- [ASCII Art Dictionary / Collection](http://www.ascii-art.de/ascii/)
- [Christopher Johnson's ASCII Art Collection](http://www.chris.com/ascii/)