# Where can I find a list of ASCII symbols?

Tags: ascii

I don't have a keypad or number lock on my laptop. I have learned how to make a heart with `<3`  but I want a list of other characters not requiring the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key

Comment: Perhaps, look at your keyboard? ;)  You're question is pretty unclear.  What do you mean by "symbols"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASCII-art unicorn one-liner](http://superuser.com/questions/174431/ascii-art-unicorn-one-liner) also see [A site for pimp my Notepad](http://superuser.com/questions/79977/a-site-for-pimp-my-notepad)

Comment: Try Googling "emoticon".  But if you're looking for character combos that convert to "smilies" or hearts when displayed, that's a function of the specific BBS/blog software you're using -- usually there will be a reference page of some sort if you look around inside the specific software environment.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Google: "list of ASCII characters"](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sugexp=eqrwrth&gs_rn=14&gs_ri=psy-ab&pq=list%20of%20ascended%20masters&cp=12&gs_id=gt&xhr=t&q=list+of+ascii+characters&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=list+of+asci&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.Yms&fp=48892eff850e335e&biw=915&bih=764).

Almost all the first hits, such as [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) and [this](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) have a nice list of all 127 ASCII codes.

Comment: I think they want plain text ASCII art (like the `<3` heart)

Comment:  They seem to be looking for "a heat" char.

Comment: Maybe it looks like a camp-fire?

Comment: @OP: MAybe edit the post to indicate that you are **not** looking for ASCII, but for [unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) signs such as [](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_%28symbol%29) ?